# Groupby and filter in pandas where all columns remain upon completion

Tags: python, pandas

I have been attempting to filter a pandas dataframe after a groupby call, and have yet to achieve my desired results.

My data which is named rd_test_AM: 
[image]

I am running a groupby call with (Year,Month,Day,DOW) so that I can find the maximum instantaneous peak by unique date. I have successfully ran code where I am able to find the maximum peak, but the hour column, integrated_load, and the ratio columns are dropped.

I am looking for a way to find the maximum instantaneous peak value by each date in my data frame. The closest I have gotten is with this code:

```
rd_test_AM['max_peak'] = rd_test_AM.groupby(['Year','Month','Day','DOW'])['instantaneous_peak'].transform('max')
```

and this is the result:

[image]

As one can see, the max_peak is printed across the existing rows. How do I condense the data frame so that it is filtered by max(instantaneous_peak) and the rest of the values (columns) in that row are shown as well?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add that data as text? Just `print(df.head(10))` and paste it as it is, also please add your expected output

Comment: Try to provide a sample data for us to reproduce the results. You can a `groupby` followed by a `pd.merge`.

Comment: @Datanovice I attempted that, but the print function concatenates my columns so not all of them are displayed. Is there a simple way to get my data frame so it can be posted in here? I've done some searching, but can't find anything.

Comment: IIUC, you can drop duplicates after calling your groupby transform `df.drop_duplicates(subset['Year','Month','Day','DOW','max_peak']`

Comment: @user3720887 try `df.head(10).to_clipboard(False)` to copy the content to clipboard and paste it into your question

Comment: @Code Different That works! Thank you. I will use that in future questions that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your instantaneous_peak values are unique (which they seem they will all be) you can do the following:

```
rd_test_AM[rd_test_AM['instantaneous_peak'].isin(rd_test_AM.groupby(['Year','Month','Day','DOW'])['instantaneous_peak'].max().tolist())]
```